# Image retrieval is slow

Tags: java, android

I'm grabbing thumbnail images from a web server in an AsynTask for each class I create as it's created. For this particular issue, I'm displaying the thumbnail and some text properties in a ListView.

The problem is that it's very slow. I considered saving each image to the device the first time it's needed and then each other time, I could just pull it from a database. I'm not sure if this is ideal or not because the image may or may not be updated on the server. In my opinion, I think it's best to always grab the images on the fly just in case there are new ones to grab.

I'd like some suggestions from all you fine folks about this.

Note: I've also tried getting the images in a ListView adapter but 1) it gets each image each and every time the ListView is scrolled and 2) it's incredibly buggy because as each image downloads, I can watch the images appear in the wrong listview item and then it magically corrects itself after a while. This wasn't at all ideal so that's why I moved the code to the class.

I'd appreciate any advice that's thrown my way.

Here's the getter for the image that lives in the class. This works fine after the image is downloaded the first time but not so well during that initial run.

```
public Bitmap GetThumbnail_xlarge() throws Exception {

    if(_thumbnail_xlarge == null ) {
        if( _thumbnailBasePath != null) {
            try {new DownloadImageTask(_thumbnail_xlarge).execute(_thumbnailBasePath + "/portrait_xlarge." + _thumbnailExtension); }
            catch (Exception e) {} //TODO: The extension could be incorrect. Do nothing for now.
        }
        else{ throw new Exception("You must set the thumbnail path before getting the image"); }
    }

    return _thumbnail_xlarge;
}
```

And, here is the class that does the work. Please note that this is a private class inside of the class where the image property lives:

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        Bitmap bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(Bitmap bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) { _thumbnail_xlarge = result; }
    }
```

I can't think of anything else that might be pertinent at this time. Please ask me for more information if necessary and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's incredibly useful to save images locally for later use. This called caching by the way. It's useful, as you are saving resources and you can reduce network requests which are using plenty of them.

If the images are big you can use the WebP format. WebP is an image format which is "lossless and lossy compression for images on the web. WebP lossless images are 26% smaller in size compared to PNGs. WebP lossy images are 25-34% smaller in size compared to JPEG images at equivalent SSIM index."
More info regarding WebP format you can find here: https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/?csw=1

Also if you want to load images smoothly on a ListView you have to use the ViewHolder pattern. More info here: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder